# Get ready for the Winter Bash!

Tags: discussion, winterbash

[In 2011, the Gaming Stack Exchange hosted an event called Hat Dash](https://web.archive.org/web/20120111011407/https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

[image]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

This year, Stack Exchange is expanding the promotion to any site that wants to participate.

Here's the run down:

- The event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on [http://winterba.sh](https://web.archive.org/web/20121231230743/http://winterba.sh/). That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available.
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

Comment: Post stolen from  http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5240/69203

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aaaand it has started!

[image]

(yes, that's a [secret hat](https://web.archive.org/web/20121222044708/http://winterba.sh/faq) :D)